# How to make payment into Google Play for uploading an application

Tags: android, uploading

As I am trying to use my State Bank of India Visa Debit Card but its showing an error message as "Invalid Credit Card"...Please I need help..

Answer (score 1):

State Bank of India's debit cards are not supported in Google wallet,
Before using your cards in Google wallet or Paypal like international sites you must activate your card for international usage by contacting your bank
This link will help you
[Indian debit card support in Google wallet, Paypal etc](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiI35_dwqHHAhVIUI4KHSS7BNA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.isaumya.com%2Fpaypal-google-wallet-indian-debit-card-support%2F&ei=YCzKVYivMMiguQSk9pKADQ&usg=AFQjCNHuT1C59JPBxvXptpR3UsxjXU-VQw&sig2=2qSZCoA36tVBMd__G9tKLw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E)